# ImageJ - How to import and display a mesh?

Tags: java, computational-geometry, mesh, imagej

How can one open and display a mesh (either using the .obj, .stl or .dxf formats) on ImageJ?

I have tried to open the files through file/open but got nothing displaying using the [3DViewer](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/3d-viewer/) or the [Interactive 3D Surface Plot](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/surface-plot-3d.html) plugins? I did get the list on the image below when I opened the obj...

I had a look at the [tutorials](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/examples/index.html) and this [paper](http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=tutorial:working:workshop3d.pdf).

[image: ImageJ WaveFront import]

Comment: I've never used ImageJ before, but from reading a bit about it, it seems it's suited for images, not typical 3D mesh files. The 3D capabilities of ImageJ are related to volumetric data, which is 3D data, but derived from images, not a stream of 3D vertices and faces. If you want to have a look at .obj/.stl/.dxf files, I recommend trying [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you opened it using ImageJ's File->Open command. You should instead open the 3D Viewer first and click on File->Import surfaces->Wavefront (for .obj files) or File->Import surfaces->STL (for .stl files obviously). Important: You have to do this in the 3D Viewer's menu bar.

You can find plenty of information about the 3D Viewer at http://3dviewer.neurofly.de

Hope that helps...

Bene