# Converting ModelNet40 .off files to HDF5 voxel files

Tags: 3d, imagej, scientific-computing

I am attempting to use the ModelNet40 set of training data. The tools I have found require hdf5 voxel files, apparently exported from ImageJ.

I have .off files from the ModelNet40 set of data, which I can convert to .obj and following the instructions on this SO answer was able to import the .obj file:

[ImageJ - How to import and display a mesh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672807/imagej-how-to-import-and-display-a-mesh)

When I attempt to use the Plugins -> BigDataViewer -> Export Current Image as XML/HDF5 I receive "Please open an image first" error. How can I create hdf5 voxel files from the dataset?

Comment: There are only a limited subset of people capable of answering this question. I suggest you post it on http://forum.imagej.net/. You probably want to mention `@tpietzsch`.